# Delete Facebook photo using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How can I delete a Facebook photo.

I'm using Facebook C# SDK :

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(acces_token);
fb.DeleteComplete += (s, e) => { //... };
fb.DeleteAsync("/" + photo_id);
```

It seems that doesn't work.My photo is still on my Facebook album.
Do I need additional permissions besides "user_photos"?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't delete photo via Facebook API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6337969/cant-delete-photo-via-facebook-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

> > fb.DeleteAsync("/photos/" + photo_id);

instead of just this...

> > fb.DeleteAsync("/" + photo_id);